# granting local account software install permission

Tags: windows

I have a stand alone W2K8 server used by our vendor. I created them a local account and made part of Power User group. This group is insufficient, they are not allowed to install any software. How can I allow the local account to install software besides local admin group.

I checked the local security policy, user rights assignment but nothing there to me would allow this. I also check UAC, but no luck. Maybe i'm doing something wrong, can anybody guide me?

Thanks

Comment: AppLocker, not exactly a quick fix though. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723678(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Power users has been [depricated](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steriley/archive/2008/02/11/plan-now-to-eliminate-power-users-from-your-domains.aspx) since Vista/2008 was released.

Answer (score 2):

They will need to be members of the `Administrators` group, or you will need to give their user accounts r/w access to the registry branches and local filesystem where each app that you want them to install needs to write to.

Power users is useless now, and only exists for legacy reasons.